# Use of the word 'attention' in the sentence

Tags: meaning-in-context

The word 'attention' has many definitions according to the context. I'd like to know what definition it has in the sentence below.

> I tried my best to give as much **attention** as possible to each patient.

Definition 1. *the act or power of carefully thinking about, listening to, or watching someone or something.*

Definition 2. *special care or treatment.*

Does the word 'attention' have definition 1 or 2? As an English learner, I have lots of things to understand clearly.

Comment: Definition 1 would be like "Pay *attention* to the teacher."

Answer (score 1):

*Attention* in this case means *care.*

So, *attending to patients* means that you *take care of them.*